# Auto-correcting dynamic variables

Tags: lua

I'm working on a lot of dynamic variables, and they must follow their original definition for the code to not give visual errors, it's about an elements of a ui and there are a lot of random variables, so here is a simpler example instead:

```
input = io.read()
inputDouble = 2*input
inputHalf = input/2
afterInputDouble = inputDouble+1
beforeInputDouble = inputDouble-1
afterInputHalf = inputHalf+1
beforeInputHalf = inputHalf-1
```

Is there a way I can change any variables i like say

```
inputHalf = 10
```

and the set of variables that are defined using the variable `inputHalf` will also update to correct themselves, like `afterInputHalf` and `beforeInputHalf`.

I also cannot just recall them by their definition like:

```
inputHalf = 10
afterInputHalf = inputHalf+1
beforeInputHalf = inputHalf-1
```

because i would be repeating a lot of lines for a lot of times every time i want to edit an element.

Is there a way to correct the variables again starting from the change or a better way I could structure the variables before defining them so every time i change something the other variables will also change to maintain their definition?

Comment: I'm confused by the question

Comment: my variables are elements of a gui. so when resizing something i have to edit a certain elements, but doing so will render the other parts wrong. like if i have a box inside a box, and i change the size of the outer box, i need the inner box to also change.

Comment: __index and recursion

Comment: However in a GUI based format whenever you draw the GUI you should check, changing the inner properties don't make a lot of sense

Answer (score 2):

simple variables don't update themselves. You can use functions to do that.

so instead of

```
inputDouble = 2 * input
```

do something like

```
inputDouble = function () return 2 * input end
```

then use `inputDouble()` instead of `inputDouble`

This way inputDouble's value will always be updated when you call it.